# Why does this regular expression return the preceding character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get every occurrence of a character (d) that is not preceded by one of a few other characters (a, b, or c).  This following regular expression works and returns the character I want, but it also returns the character immediately before it (like a space or another character).

```
var rgx = /(?:[^abc])d/
var string = 'abcd d de cd ad da bd'
```

You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/bF4gZ2/2).

Normally I would use a negative lookbehind, but I'm working in javascript and this seemed like a simple workaround for what I need.  I know that there are workarounds for implementing lookbehind in JS, but I'm interested in understanding why this regular expression works the way it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 2 different captured groups:

```
var rgx = /(?:^|[^abc])(d)/;
```

To get preceding character separately from your match in absence of a lookbehind features in Javascript regex engine.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bF4gZ2/4)

Comment: Thank you, that makes total sense.  I'm still not sure I understand why it's returning it in the list of matches at all though.

Comment: It is returning because `(^|[^abc])` is **not a zero width assertion** as compared to negative lookbehind. It will be returned in matches but you can discard it.

Comment: See my answer for what @anubhava means.

Comment: Great - thank you both for clarifying.  Sorry, I didn't notice your demo wasn't using the non-capturing group at first, hence my previous question.  Accepted.

Comment: You're most welcome. For using lookbehind and other advanced regex features consider using http://xregexp.com/ RegEx library in JS